# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, foreign-keys

**NOTE:** **Before marking it as Duplicate, i want to tell you guys that i've gone through all these related problems in stackoverflow and other websites, but i didn't get any suitable solution, so that's why i am here for the help.**

I have two tables: **employees** and **fines**

In **fines** table `fine_id` is the **PK** and `employee_id` is the **FK** references to **employees** table **PK** `employee_id`.

Now, i am creating `fine_id` (column in table **employees**) as a **FK** reference to `fine_id` in **fines** table.

i am adding **constraints** via **XAMPP PHPMYADMIN** it auto generates my query which is:

`ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT fine_fk FOREIGN KEY (fine_id) REFERENCES fines(fine_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

But, I am getting this error while running this `SQL Query`

## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ems_db`.`#sql-dd4_35`, CONSTRAINT `fine_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fine_id`) REFERENCES `fines` (`fine_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here are attached images:

**employees** table

[image]

**fines** table

[image]

**error**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

somehow i managed to solve my issue myself,

the problem was that in my **employees** table i have the column `fine_id` which i want to make a **FK**, that column value was empty in my existing record in **employees** table, although i have values in my **fines** table, but the column `fine_id` in **employees** table was not filled, with the corresponding `fine_id` of **fines** table, so before creating **FK** i have filled my column with the correct **ID's** of **fines** table, and my problem was gone away.

Comment: Since i had the exact same problem, i would like to suggest truncating the table before trying to add the constraint, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use query to set foreign key. Not graphically. That worked for me!